# Is it possible to upgrade directly from 15.04 to 16.04?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop. Is it possible to upgrade directly to 16.04?

Comment: 15.04 has gone end of life a while back so is off topic on AU. Besides that: no. You should have upgraded to 15.10 when it was still possible.

Comment: Follow the link here https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release for instructions on how to upgrade an EOL release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- No you can not upgrade from 15.04 directly to 16.04.
- You have to update from 15.04 over 15.10 to 16.04.

Just as additional information:

- Upgrading from LTS to LTS works (example: 14.04 to 16.04 would be possible)